# Keep hover while on scrollbar

Tags: html, css, hover, scrollbar

I have this menu that when I hover on certain items, it dropsdown a list of new items. Sometimes this list is bigger than the browser window, so user need to scroll the page down to be able to see the whole list. The problem is that when the mouse reacher the scrollbar naturaly the menu lose it's hover function. I need to fix that asap, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that if the menu has that long, you need to redesign your interface. Try a sub-menu structure with multiple levels or even spread things across more than one page.

Comment: Seems odd to have a menu list with items larger than the browser window. Maybe you could benefit from nested menus?

Comment: The layout is not mine, so I can't change it by myself. Gonna talk to the designer here. Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing hover on the menu item, maybe you should do an onclick event. This would allow the menu to appear on click and then when the user clicks the menu again it could make the sub-menu hide. This would allow you to scroll down the page and still have the sub-menu showing.

BTW, this assumes you cannot break the menu down into sub-menus like Nathan MacInnes mentioned.

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that I have menus with 3 levels. However, I would rip this off from the website, nut I didn't work on this layout, so it's not my fault if I leave it without the scrollm right? lol Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the user has to move the mouse off of the menu, it naturally should close. Maybe you should try making the menu shorter, or try making the menu itself scroll?

Comment: The layout is not mine, so I can't change it by myself. Gonna talk to the designer here. Thanks anyway guys!